# C# get column header text and first row text from selected cell

Tags: c#

I want to get the corresponding column header text and first row of the cell a user selected.

I have tried this but I get no message pop up.

```
private void factoriesTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedRow = "";
    string selectedColumn = "";

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in factoriesTable.SelectedRows)
    {
        selectedRow = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(selectedRow);
    }

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in factoriesTable.SelectedColumns)
    {
        selectedColumn = column.HeaderText.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(selectedColumn);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking to get the selected cell and its column header you can do something like this:

```
string cellValue = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
int colIndex = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex
string columnHeader = dataGridView.Columns[colIndex].HeaderText;
```

Or a one liner to get the column header:

```
string columnHeader = dataGridView.SelectedCells[0].OwningColumn.HeaderText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This...

int x = billinggridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
string text = billinggridview.Columns[x].HeaderText;